# How to test a expressJS endpoint using jest which includes Joi for request validation?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs, joi

I have been working on an expressJS application in which I have wrote an endpoint which sends a call to user for OTP verification here is the definition of the endpoint function:

```
  async sendVoiceCall(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const validationSchema = Joi.object({
        phoneNo: Joi.string().required(),
      });
      const { error } = validationSchema.validate(req.body);
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error occured.....");
        return next(error);
      }
      const { phoneNo } = req.body;
      const select =
        "-connectionsCount -competitionsCount -winsCount -audienceCount -prizesGeneratedCount -blackDiamonds -createdAt -updatedAt";
      const user = await User.findOne({ phoneNo: phoneNo }).select(select);
      if (!user) {
        throw new CustomErrorHandler(
          404,
          "User with the provided phone does not exists"
        );
      }
      // generate the OTP and save that with its expiry in the dB
      const otp = functions.generateOTP();
      await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: user._id },
        {
          otp,
          otpDateTime: moment().add(5, "minute"),
        },
        { new: true }
      );
      const message = `Your OTP code is: ${otp}`;
      await sendVoiceCall(phoneNo, message);
      res.status(200);
      res.json({ message: "Call has initiated successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error);
    }
  },
```

Here sendVoice() function is actually uses AWS Pinpoint service to send calls to users for OTP.

I am trying to test this function using jest here is what I have done so far:

```
// Import necessary modules and dependencies
import sendVoiceCall from "../../../../utils/sendVoiceCall";
import User from "../../../../model/user";
import functions from "../../../../utils/functions";
import Joi from "joi";
import UsersController from "../UsersController";

jest.mock("../../../../services/CustomErrorhandler");
jest.mock("../../../../model/user");
jest.mock("../../../../utils/functions");
jest.mock("../../../../utils/sendVoiceCall");
jest.mock("joi", () => ({
  object: jest.fn((x) => x),
  validate: jest.fn((x) => x),
  string: jest.fn((x) => x),
}));

describe("sendVoiceCall", () => {
  it("should initiate a voice call with a valid phone number", async () => {
    // Mock request and response object
    const req = {
      body: {
        phoneNo: "+923132290956",
      },
    };
    const res = {
      status: jest.fn((x) => x),
      json: jest.fn((x) => x),
    };
    const next = jest.fn();

    // Mock User.findOne to return a user
    // Mock the findOne method and return a query builder object
    User.findOne = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();

    // Mock the select method on the query builder
    User.findOne.mockReturnValueOnce({
      select: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        _id: "user_id",
      }),
    });

    // Mock functions.generateOTP to return a fixed OTP value
    functions.generateOTP.mockReturnValue("123456");

    await User.findOneAndUpdate.mockResolvedValue({
      _id: "user_id",
    });

    // Mock the sendVoiceCall utility function
    sendVoiceCall.mockResolvedValue("Call initiated successfully");

    const schema = Joi.object({
      key: Joi.string(),
    });
    const value = {
      key: "3",
    };

    // Call the function
    await UsersController.sendVoiceCall(req, res, next);

    // Assertions
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
    expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      message: "Call has initiated successfully",
    });
  });

  it("should handle errors when initiating a voice call", async () => {
    // Mock dependencies and request object
    const req = {
      body: {
        phoneNo: "+1234567890", // Replace with a valid phone number
      },
    };
    const res = {
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      json: jest.fn(),
    };
    const next = jest.fn();

    // Mock validation schema to return no error
    Joi.object().mockReturnValue({
      validate: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ error: null }),
    });

    // Mock User.findOne to return no user (user not found)
    User.findOne.mockResolvedValue(null);

    // Call the function
    await sendVoiceCall(req, res, next);

    // Assertions
    expect(next).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      new CustomErrorHandler(404, "User with the provided phone does not exist")
    );
  });

  it("should handle validation errors", async () => {
    // Mock dependencies and request object
    const req = {
      body: {
        phoneNo: "", // An empty phone number (invalid)
      },
    };
    const res = {
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      json: jest.fn(),
    };
    const next = jest.fn();

    // Mock validation schema to return an error
    Joi.object().mockReturnValue({
      validate: jest
        .fn()
        .mockReturnValue({ error: new Error("Validation error") }),
    });

    // Call the function
    await sendVoiceCall(req, res, next);

    // Assertions
    expect(next).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Error("Validation error"));
  });
});
```

I have tried three test cases but when I am running this test file, then all of my test cases are failing with these errors:

```
  ✕ should initiate a voice call with a valid phone number (15 ms)
    ✕ should handle errors when initiating a voice call (2 ms)
    ✕ should handle validation errors (1 ms)

  ● sendVoiceCall › should initiate a voice call with a valid phone number

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: 200

    Number of calls: 0

      62 |
      63 |     // Assertions
    > 64 |     expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
         |                        ^
      65 |     expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      66 |       message: "Call has initiated successfully",
      67 |     });


  ● sendVoiceCall › should handle errors when initiating a voice call

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mockReturnValue')

      82 |
      83 |     // Mock validation schema to return no error
    > 84 |     Joi.object().mockReturnValue({
         |                 ^
      85 |       validate: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ error: null }),
      86 |     });


  ● sendVoiceCall › should handle validation errors

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mockReturnValue')

      112 |
      113 |     // Mock validation schema to return an error
    > 114 |     Joi.object().mockReturnValue({
          |                 ^
      115 |       validate: jest
      116 |         .fn()
      117 |         .mockReturnValue({ error: new Error("Validation error") }),


Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       3 failed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.932 s, estimated 6 s
```

Please tell me how can I write unit test for my function **sendVoiceCall** using jest including **Joi** validation.

Comment: _Don't_ unit test controllers - don't mock things you don't own, like Express's API. This is too coupled to the transport layer to isolate. Test at an integration level, describe it in request and response terms with e.g. Supertest.

Comment: Can you give me some more explanation on how to do testing at this high level?

Comment: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2023/May/23/js-tdd-ohm.html